# Getting error in Python: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'

Tags: python, json, django

Getting error in Python: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'json'`

How to solve this error?

Below is my code:
**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
#from django.shortcuts import render
import json
import dotenv
#from . models import Contect
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from rest_framework.response import Response
# Create your views here.
    
def home1(request):
   # get the list of todos
   response1 = request.GET.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
   # transfor the response to json objects
   todos = response1.json()
   return render(request, "main_app/home.html", {"todos": todos})
```

Answer (score 0):

Two errors I see here:
Change this:

`response1 = request.GET.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')`

TO:

`response1 = request.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')`

Also, check first if `response1` is not empty. It is empty, hence you get that error.

Comment: Then this error is accor
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @SharandeepSingh: Since this is Django, I guess your original code would work. Just first validate if `response1` is not empty.

Comment: Did it work now?

Answer (score 0):

You can try retrieving the JSON values from the URL following this method -

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def home1(request):
    # get the list of todos
    response1 = urlopen('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
    # transfor the response to json objects
    todos = json.loads(response1.read())
    return render(request, "main_app/home.html", {"todos": todos})
```

`todos` will hold all the JSON values that the URL provided.